# UWP BackgroundDownloader with self signed SSL certificate

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-transfer

Is there a way to download some data, with a BackgroundDownloader from the BackgroundTransfer namespace, from a server, which uses a self signed SSL certificate? On Windows 10 Mobile, i can install my self signed SSL cert, and then it works, but on the Desktop this method gives me no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if some user is interested about the solution: If you install the certificate, you Need to make sure, you install it not only for the actual user, you NEED to install it for EVERY user on the device. So now it works with the BackgroundTransfer Namespace in an UWP app on Desktop.

Best regards